# C# Generics: Reference types vs. Value Types

Tags: c#, generics

*I've faced a lot of confusion with regards to differences between generic reference types vs. generic value types whilst writing my API.*

What are the differences with regards to constraints and functionalities (most important/easily overlooked) between the two?

```
class ReferenceGeneric <T> where ???
{

}
```

and

```
struct ValueGeneric <T>: where ???
{

}
```

**Edit #1** Just to clarify the question and what I am after: I want to know what you can do with Generic reference types AND cannot do with generic value types (and vice versa)

**Edit #2** Further clarifications: How can T be constrained if generic type is reference or value type? Are there differences as to how each type can be constrained?

Comment: You question is very confusing... there is an answer out there but what are you after?

Comment: you said you have to tweak sometimes. can you give an example?

Comment: I've elaborated on the  question in the edit.

Comment: your question would be more interesting if you phrased it as:  what can you do differently in A and B. A) class Foo<T> where T: struct { }  B) class Foo<T> where T : class { }

Comment: Perhaps, but I was interested in something else -- as stated above :)

Comment: Well then the answer is that the <T> makes no difference whatsoever in this case then. short and sweet :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Be aware that anything declared as a struct is *always* a value type, and anything declared as a class is *always* a reference type. In other words, `List<int>` is still a reference type, and if you had:

```
struct Foo<T>
{
    T value;
}
```

then `Foo<string>` would still be a value type.

As for what you can *do* with the generic types - they really just follow the normal rules for value types and reference types; as for what you can do with an value of type `T` *within* the type, that depends on whether/how `T` is constrained. It doesn't vary based on whether the generic type itself is a struct or a class though.

EDIT: Sasha mentions `Nullable<T>` in the comments. I'm not sure what "exception" is meant here - other than `Nullable<T>` doesn't satisfy either the "`where T : struct`" or "`where T : class`" constraint. It's still a value type though (which is part of the point).

Comment: Jon, there is an exception if the struct type is Nullable. Would you elaborate on that as well? thx

Comment: " anything declared as a class is always a value type" typo?

Comment: Jon: Fixed your typo to avoid confusion :)

Answer (score 11):

In response to Edit2: You can limit the types allowed to reference or value by the following:

Reference:

```
class ReferenceGeneric <T> where T: class
{

}
```

Value:

```
struct ValueGeneric <T> where T: struct 
{


}
```

From the following page on MSDN
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx

Comment: Can you constrain struct by class:                                  struct ValueGeneric <T> where T: class 
{


}